# Formula for Symmetry Factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

In $\phi^3$ theory, are there any formula for determining the Symmetry factor as that is found for the $\phi^4$ theory in any standard book of Quantum Field Theory?

Comment: You may find the following links interesting : http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108088, http://mathoverflow.net/q/26897/

Comment: could you give an example of a Lagrangian? And a related potential?

Comment: $$  \mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} Z_\phi \partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi -\frac{1}{2} Z_m m^2 \phi^2 + \frac{1}{6} Z_g g \phi^3 + Y\phi $$

Srednicki eqn. (9.1)

Comment: Any textbook of QFT explains how to write the symmetry factors for *any* fields, interaction vertices, and diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peskin and Schroeder provide a sufficiently detailed explanation regarding the computation of symmetry factors for Feynman diagrams. The [paper by Palmer et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108088) present a general formula,

$$S=\frac{1}{R}\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{D_1}\left( \frac{1}{2!}\right)^{D_2}\left( \frac{1}{3!}\right)^{D_3}\left( \frac{1}{4!}\right)^{D_4}$$

where the constants are defined in their paper, which require an understanding of the derivation and its notation. The expression is applicable to QED, QCD and $\phi^{3,4}$ theory but generalizable to others. For a diagram such as (considered in their paper as figure 1),

[image]

For this case, $D_1=D_3=D_4=0$, $R=1$ and $D_2$ = 1 which yield, $S=1/2$ as expected. In [Dong's paper](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/pdf/0907.0859.pdf) for real and complex scalar field theories, he presents the general formula,

$$S=g2^\beta 2^d \prod_n \left( n!\right)^{\alpha_n}$$

where (quoting from the paper): $g$ is the number of of interchanges of vertices leaving the diagram topologically unchanged, $\beta$ is the number of lines connecting a vertex to itself, $d$ is the number of double bubbles, and $\alpha_n$ is the number of vertex pairs connected by $n$ identical lines.

Comment: This is extremely confusing since the first formula produces an inverse of an integer, whereas the second one produces an integer. Clearly $S^{-1}$ is meant in one of them. Secondly, taking external vertices into account is the trickiest part, and it's not emphasized in either description. It would seem that $g$ for this diagram is $2$ since you can permute $b,c$ without changing the topology. However the "topology" includes the labels $Y,Z$, so this interchange in fact is not allowed, so the only contribution is from $\alpha_2=1.$

Comment: In this sense, Palmer's definition is much more carefully worded: "$R$ is the number of ways to permute the internal indices [vertices] and produce an identical set of propagators". This description makes it clear that swapping $b$ and $c$ is not a valid symmetry.